# issue with parsing text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to do a `re.sub` to replace a repeating string in my python string and have hit a wall.

The string I am trying to find and replace is `" *. in *."` All those are literal, i.e. not repeating spaces followed by anything etc etc.

I have tried many things, here is the one in my console at the present:

```
message = re.sub(r"([\s][*][.][\s]in[\s][*][.])+", " *. in *.",message)
```

Can someone point me to the error in my ways?

Comment: Ok, so you want to *shrink* the multiple " *. in *." to just one? See http://ideone.com/wgEVsR. If you enable `re.U` flag, `\s` will also mach all Unicode whitespace. Try your `message = re.sub(r"([\s][*][.][\s]in[\s][*][.])+", " *. in *.",message, flags=re.U)`

Comment: First of all you should escape dot: `[\.]`

Comment: @Shpionus: No, one does not have to escape the dot inside a character class.

Comment: @Bob: see http://ideone.com/vy82qN

Comment: Here is the good news: **none** of those square brackets are necessary. That's why your `.*` combo fails, by the way.

Comment: Don't put `\s` inside a group `[]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: obsolete but actually that doesn't do any harm either, This `[*]` does, as it destroys its magic properties.

Comment: @RadLexus the square brackets are being used to escape the literal `*` and `.` characters, so they do serve *some* purpose. That's not the way you usually do it.

Comment: @RadLexus I think that's the point, they don't want `*` to have magic properties in this example.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ah you're right - OP wants literal stars and dots. Still, massive overkill of square brackets.

Comment: Well, the point is that the OP regex is correct as per the description. Without the exact input string, I cannot repro.

Comment: @Bob, if you need help, please update the question with the exact sample string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is kind of clunky, but it works. The problem is you are replacing it with *the exact same string*:

```
>>> import re
>>> message = 'string I am trying to find and replace is " *. in *." All those are literal'
>>> re.sub(r"([\s][*][.][\s]in[\s][*][.])+", " *. in *.", message)
'string I am trying to find and replace is " *. in *." All those are literal'
>>> re.sub(r"([\s][*][.][\s]in[\s][*][.])+", "wot", message)
'string I am trying to find and replace is "wot" All those are literal'
```

See? It works!

Your regex is 'clunky' because the only two magical characters that you want to match *literally* are `*` and `.`. While the square brackets indeed remove their magic properties, it's common practice to just escape them with a backslash. All other characters and sequences do *not* need brackets, so all you need is

```
re.sub(r"(\s\*\.\sin\s\*\.)+", "wot", message)
```

Comment: *I have been trying to do a re.sub to replace a **repeating** string* - OP tries to shrink several repeating substrings with just 1 occurrence. See my comment to the question. OP regex and solution just work. Or should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I just tested with repeated occurrences of `*. in *.` and that still works. A string of literal repeats get replaced with a single `wot`, and so do single occurrences. OP should add some more examples, then.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.  I copied and pasted several suggestions above and the repeated strings still did not shrink.  When I used the "wot" replacement, the string became "wot in wot".  To solve this, I changed tactics to first replacing the "*." with another string and then shrunk that with essentially the code suggested by Wiktor and Rad.

Comment: I should also mention that when I pasted my input string into the idoneit.com website with Wiktor's solution, it worked, so something local??  Not sure, moving on.  Thanks again.